# Shell script result in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet.I created a module and wrote a simple 'Hello World'shell script in the files folder.I want to execute the script and see the  result.

This is my manifest.

```
class module {
    file {'puppet_test.sh':,
        ensure =>present,
        owner =>'frank',
        mode =>'0755',
        path =>'/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh',
        source =>'puppet:///module//puppet_test.sh',
        notify =>Exec['run_my_script'],
    }

    # exec{'/puppet_firstscript/puppet_test.sh':require=>[File'/puppet_firstscript/puppet.sh']}
    exec{
        'run_my_script':
            command => '/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh',
            #refreshonly=true
    }
}
```

If there are any issues in manifest please tell me so.

After editing this is the init.pp for my puppet

```
class module {
        file {'puppet_test.sh':,
        ensure =>present,
        owner =>'frank',
        mode =>'0755',
        path =>'/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh',
        source =>'puppet:///modules/module/puppet_test.sh',
        notify =>Exec['run_my_script'],
             }
        exec{
                'run_my_script':
                command =>'/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh',            
}
```

Comment: I tried the changes but there is error "Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '/' at /data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/manifests/init.pp:58:11"

Comment: Edit your question with the error message as well as what is on the 58º line of the `init.pp` file.

Comment: this is the 58th line "command /data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh,"

Comment: There is no `=>` between command and the path, and the double quotes should be only in the path.

Comment: The init.pp was as you mentioned.It was working but it was not displaying  the output of the script.

Comment: Puppet does not display the script output except in the case of an error. This is by design. Puppet will only output something if the resource was applied, which means *executed* to `Exec` resources.

Comment: The main question I have is that what should be the source path to be mentioned in init.pp .Similarly is the command that is displayed in init.pp is correct with reference to the path and all....

Answer (score 0):

So I ran puppet-lint against the code you gave and got the following errors:

```
WARNING: puppet:// URL without modules/ found on line 7
```

The path you give to the puppet:// url requires the name of the module where the file is. So your module with this code should look like the following:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── files
│   └── puppet_test.sh
├── manifests
│   └── init.pp
└── metadata.json

2 directories, 5 files
```

Your updated code should look like this:

```
class module {
  file {'puppet_test.sh':,
    ensure => file,
    owner  =>'frank',
    mode   =>'0755',
    path  =>'/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh',
    source =>'puppet:///modules/module/puppet_test.sh',
    notify =>Exec['run_my_script'],
  }

  exec{
    'run_my_script':
      command => '/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/puppet_test/module/files/puppet_test.sh',
  }
}
```

Comment: if I execute the puppet apply command, the output is something like compiled catalog in env.....applied catalog in ..according to joao (the person above who answered the first) puppet will print the message irrespective of the error......what I want is the echo output in my script